Read a Java file using fs module (express.js)
I'm trying to use express's fs module to scan text files and display them on screen. I managed to do this in my tests using a txt file, but I'm having trouble getting the same code to work with java files.
Is it possible to read a java file or can the module only read txt files?
Basicly, my code is this:
async function readFile(req, res) {
    const filePath = path.join('C:/Users/Tester/Desktop/Test', 'Text.txt');

    fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return res.status(500).send('Error while reading file');
        }
        res.send(data);
    });
}

I just tried swapping the path field for the new field of a java project and the name of the file I want to read.
Thank you in advance for your help!

.java files are no different to .txt files. What sort of trouble are you running in to?

fs.readFile() can read any file in any format (as long as you have permission).  Did you get a specific error?  Or what was the problem you ran into?  Some java files may not be plain text (compiled binary, for example), depending upon what exactly you tried to read.

In my case, the problem is related to the path specified. The path is incorrect because of the way escape characters are treated in JavaScript strings.
When you use \ in a JavaScript string, it is treated as an escape character. For example, \n represents a new line. If you want to include a literal \ in a file path, you need to escape it, i.e. use \\.
After correcting this, my code worked
